# Issue with ColdFusion's implicit accessors

Tags: coldfusion, accessor, cfml, cfc

Issue with implicit accessors

Our development team recently discovered that we are getting multiple errors when using implicit get accessor (person.firstName) instead of generated get accessor (person.getFirstName()). Here are instructions of how to reproduce the error:

1. Create a new ColdFusion application with the following files:

Application.cfc:

```
component {
    this.invokeImplicitAccessor = true;
}
```

Person.cfc:

```
component accessors=true {
    property firstName;
}
```

index.cfm:

```
local.person = new Person();
local.person.firstName = "Zachary";

for( local.i = 0; local.i lt 1000; local.i++ ) {
    local.j = local.person.firstName;
}
```

index2.cfm:

```
local.person = new Person();
local.person.firstName = "Zachary";

for( local.i = 0; local.i lt 1000; local.i++ ) {
    local.j = local.person.getFirstName();
}
```

2. Test the index.cfm with JMeter, use 2000 threads, 10s Ram-Up Period and Loop count 1 (test plan: https://pastebin.com/nBtpL4zP)
3. In our tests the page always fails with the same error message:

Element PERSON.FIRSTNAME is undefined in LOCAL.

4. The error % we are getting with the above settings usually falls somewhere between 8 to 10 %, meaning that 160 to 200 requests out of >2000 requests fails.
5. When index2.cfm gets tested with the same settings, we don't get any errors

Here are some details about the test environment:

OS: Windows Server 2016 Standard
ColdFusion: Adobe ColdFusion 2018 Release
JMeter 5.0 (https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Is there some ColdFusion settings we could tweak? The above example application is very minimal, and we are not doing anything special, so I don't see any reasons why implicit accessors should fail, especially when generated accessors seems to pass the same test without any issues.

We appreciate any help or suggestions of what to try to get the implicit accessors working.

EDIT: Fixed index2.cfm to use get() method instead of implicit accessor.

EDIT2: Full error message/page: https://pastebin.com/budqiV1m

EDIT3: I have created a bug report for this: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4203997

Comment: The examples that you posted for index.cfm and index2.cfm are exactly the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think index2.cfm should have local j = local.person.getFirstName();

Comment: I always use explicit getters & setters. In other words, create a getFirstName() & setFirstName() method. The advantage of this, is that it gets around circular redundancy issues. Creating a method for a setter/getter also allows for better scalability.

Comment: public void setFirstName(firstname) {
 variables.firstName = arguments.firstname;
}

public string getFirstName() {
 return variables.firstName;
}

Comment: It also protects variables from being altered externally and therefore adheres to the laws of encapsulation. In other words, component variables can only be read & updated, externally, via a public method.

Comment: Using implicit accessors does not break encapsulation, nor does it prevent better scalability.
Even when you use implicit getters and setters like obj.firstName = 'Bob' it does not break encapsulation. The variables are stored within the variables scope by default, and that can only be mutated from within the object. Also, under the covers CF will actually call setFirstName(), even if it exists, even if it is a custom setter that you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The accessors are functions. If you have

```
  component accessors=true {
    property name="foo";
  }
```

The correct way to use implicit accessors is **this.getFoo()** or just **getFoo()** (inside the component) or **myComponent.getFoo()** outside the component.

*this.getFoo* is a pointer to the getter and not the getter itself. In your example, **local.j = local.person.firstName;** is setting j to a pointer to the getter and not the value of the property; it should be **person.getFirstName()** if indeed you want to use the implicit accessor.

It has not been the case for many years now that explicit getters or setters are faster (on either ACF or Lucee). You can, of course, still write them if you need them and they'll overwrite the implicit functions.

While this example is from Adobe's ORM docs, it better illustrates how implicit accessors should be used:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/coldfusion-orm/working-with-objects/generated-accessors.html

Here is a more complete explanation -- even though it's for Lucee, it works this way in ACF as well:

https://rorylaitila.gitbooks.io/lucee/content/properties.html

Finally, while not relevant to the problem, the **local** scope is a function scope and on a .cfm page just the variables scope in disguise. You can drop **local** from all of that code as it's somewhat misleading -- unless you're inside a function definition inside your .cfm page (which you shouldn't be) you're in variables scope territory and if you want to be explicit about it, variables is what you should use.

Comment: Please see https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/building-and-using-coldfusion-components/cfc-implicit-notation.html about implicit accessors.Once invokeImplicitAccessor is set to true, CF internally calls the get and set methods, when the dot notation is used (see Adobe's example). To rule out the possibility that generated accessors fail, I also repeated my original example with manually defined set and get methods (based on Adobe's example), and it didn't make any difference to using generated accessors.

Comment: Their example has `invokeImplicitAccessor = "true"` but for what it's worth, given what a basic piece of functionality this is, I would stick to using implicit accessors, forget dot notation, and also scrap the local scope. The example in the question has a lot of idiosyncratic behavior that may be obfuscating what the real problem is.